# Change PRE style but preserve whitespace distance

Tags: css, whitespace, pre, font-family

I'm displaying some content using the PRE tag, because it's vital to preserve the whitespace as is.
However, when I'm trying to change the PRE font-family, the whitespace indentation falls apart.

To be more specific, I'm building a site with song chords and their equivalent lyrics, so I need each chord to be exactly above a certain word or letter. When I style the PRE font-family, the chords are losing their relative to the letters position, even though all text is styled the same way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other posters said, you need a monospace font.  You can use CSS3 custom fonts if you want to use your own monospace font.  The easiest way to fix your problem, though, is to let the viewer's browser decide which font to use.  To make sure all viewers see your `pre` content in a monospace font, use the following.

```
pre { font-family: monospace; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's due to different widths for each letter/number with your font-family.
However you should be able to use a *monospace* font?

Comment: The problem is I'm retrieving the content from the database. I sure could use the font I liked during the song input so that the whitespace would be preserved at the database regarding the selected font, but i'm searching for a more 'portable' solution. I may need to change the css again some time :)

Answer (score 2):

yup, you need monospace fonts. here are list of some fonts that is available
http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/monospaced-fonts.htm (Google)